# find mysql innodb deadlock reason on INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have a java application, and it occurs dead lock exception on the sql below:

```
insert into voucher (
    id,
    order_id,
    voucher_code
) SELECT
    #{id},
    #{orderId},
    #{voucherCode}
    FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM voucher where order_id =  #{orderId})
```

The `order_id` is unique key.
And I am sure that it will be deadlocked when the sql is executed on concurrency.
However, I dont have permission enough to execute `show engine innodb status`, so I fail to get information about the deadlock exception.

I try to reproduce the problem in a lab environment.
table test is below:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`info` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`order_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uni_order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and I execute two sqls in two different sessions:

```
insert into test(info,order_id) select '12345',sleep(10) from dual where not exists (select info from test where info='12345');  
insert into test(info,order_id) select '12345',234 from dual where not exists (select info from test where info='12345');
```

deadlock log is below：

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-06-20 17:26:54 700000a83000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2321, ACTIVE 9 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x700000a3f000, query id 29 localhost root executing
insert into test(info,order_id) select '12345',234 from dual where not exists (select info from test where info='12345')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 9 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`test` trx id 2321 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2320, ACTIVE 10 sec setting auto-inc lock
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
3 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 0x700000a83000, query id 28 localhost root User sleep
insert into test(info,order_id) select '12345',sleep(10) from dual where not exists (select info from test where info='12345')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 9 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`test` trx id 2320 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
TABLE LOCK table `test`.`test` trx id 2320 lock mode AUTO-INC waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I supposed that the subquery `select info from test where info=‘12345’` may hold SLock, and `insert into … select` want XLock.
But I fail to find the offical document to support my point.

So my question is below:
1. is my reproduce design right?
2. is my supposal(the subquery `select info from test where info=‘12345’` may hold SLock) right? Any offical document can support my supposal?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `INSERT ... SELECT`, by default MySQL is locking all rows in SELECT.
If you change isolation level to READ-COMMITTED, then rows in `SELECT` is not locked. In your case this should solve deadlock problem.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

PS:I suggest to read about isolation levels and understand differences between them.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html

> INSERT INTO T SELECT ... FROM S WHERE ... sets an exclusive index
>   record lock (without a gap lock) on each row inserted into T. If the
>   transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED, or
>   innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog is enabled and the transaction
>   isolation level is not SERIALIZABLE, InnoDB does the search on S as a
>   consistent read (no locks). Otherwise, InnoDB sets shared next-key
>   locks on rows from S. InnoDB has to set locks in the latter case: In
>   roll-forward recovery from a backup, every SQL statement must be
>   executed in exactly the same way it was done originally.
>
> CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ... performs the SELECT with shared next-key
>   locks or as a consistent read, as for INSERT ... SELECT.
>
> When a SELECT is used in the constructs REPLACE INTO t SELECT ... FROM
>   s WHERE ... or UPDATE t ... WHERE col IN (SELECT ... FROM s ...),
>   InnoDB sets shared next-key locks on rows from table s.

Comment: i want to find the reason of the deadlock in this case, instead of the solution.

Comment: Will it be not safe? e.g., Transaction 1 and Transaction 2 both get true from `where not exists (select info from test where info='12345')` , then 2 transcations both finish inserting, which is not what we expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are working too hard.  I think does the same thing:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO voucher
    ( id, order_id, voucher_code )
    VALUES
    ( #{id}, #{orderId}, #{voucherCode} )
```

If orderId is already in the table, the `UNIQUE` key will complain, but `IGNORE` will silence it.

But... You have another problem...  Your query (and mine) checks `id` for being a duplicate.  That is, there can be 2 things hitting `UNIQUE`, but you check for only one.

*Normally*, one would simply leave out `id`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO voucher
    ( order_id, voucher_code )
    VALUES
    ( #{orderId}, #{voucherCode} )
```

But, you probably want to get the new `id` when the insert occurs?  So...

```
INSERT INTO voucher
    ( order_id, voucher_code )
    VALUES
    ( #{orderId}, #{voucherCode} )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If, on the other hand, you really want to play with *both* unique keys, consider this messy statement:

```
REPLACE INTO voucher
    ( id, order_id, voucher_code )
    VALUES
    ( #{id}, #{orderId}, #{voucherCode} )
```

That will

1. `DELETE` any row(s) that match *either* unique key (id or order_id)
2. `INSERT` the values.  (Since you specified `id`, `AUTO_INCREMENT` has no effect.)

Now, let's carry this a step further.  Why have two unique keys?  Can't you get rid of `id` completely?  And then make `order_id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Now, you have simplified the schema, simplified the query, and very likely eliminated the deadlock.